# Android RecyclerView: Change layout file LIST to GRID onOptionItemSelected

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I am developing an Android Application for Online Shopping. I have created following view for List of Products using `RecyclerView`, in that i want to change view **on selecting option menu item**:

I have created following **adapter** named `ProductAdapter`, in that I have implemented code for changing layout in `onCreateViewHolder` for selecting layout file based on boolean value.

**Code of Adapter `ProductAdapter`**:

```
    /***
     * ADAPTER for Product to binding rows in List
     */
    private class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductRowHolder> {

        private List<Product> productList;

        private Context mContext;

        public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Product> feedItemList) {
            this.productList = feedItemList;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public ProductRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(isProductViewAsList ? R.layout.product_row_layout_list : R.layout.product_row_layout_grid, null);
            ProductRowHolder mh = new ProductRowHolder(v);
            return mh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ProductRowHolder  productRowHolder, int i) {
            Product prodItem = productList.get(i);

//            Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getName())
//                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
//                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
//                    .into(productRowHolder.thumbnail);


            double price = prodItem.getPrice();
            double discount = prodItem.getDiscount();
            double discountedPrice = price - (price * discount / 100);

            String code = "";
            if(prodItem.getCode() != null)
                code = "[" + prodItem.getCode() + "] ";

            productRowHolder.prodIsNewView.setVisibility(prodItem.getIsNew() == 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
            productRowHolder.prodNameView.setText(code + prodItem.getName());
            productRowHolder.prodOriginalRateView.setText("Rs." + new BigDecimal(price).setScale(2,RoundingMode.DOWN));
            productRowHolder.prodDiscView.setText("" + new BigDecimal(discount).setScale(2,RoundingMode.DOWN) + "% off");
            productRowHolder.prodDiscRateView.setText("Rs." + new BigDecimal(discountedPrice).setScale(2,RoundingMode.DOWN));

            productRowHolder.prodOriginalRateView.setPaintFlags(productRowHolder.prodOriginalRateView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (null != productList ? productList.size() : 0);
        }

        public class ProductRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            //Declaration of Views

            public ProductRowHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                view.setOnClickListener(this);

                //Find Views
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //Onclick of row
            }
        }
    }
```

After that i have done code for Changing `RecyclerView` layout from `List` to `Grid` and Vice Versa in `onOptionsItemSelected`, here i am calling `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` so it will call adapter again and change value.

**onOptionsItemSelected**:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.product_show_as_view:
                isProductViewAsList = !isProductViewAsList;
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(isProductViewAsList ? new LinearLayoutManager(this) : new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I got little bit success like:

Image of `Grid` layout:

[image]

Image of `List` layout:

[image]

**BUT NOW WHEN I SCROLL and then CHANGING VIEW is Displaying** like:

`Grid` layout:

[image]

`List` layout:

[image]

**I dont know why it happens after scrolling. Is there any other way to change view like this.**

> Today i just saw that this problem is because of `ImageView`, without it  working perfectly.

Help please, You help will be appreciated.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933117/2649012

Comment: use this RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

Comment: its `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` but not working for me. any other solution?

Comment: I think this respost can help you:
[RecyclerView: how to clear cached/recycled views?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27961601/4098739)

Comment: have you solved this yet?

Comment: I have posted my solution as answer @Harsha

Comment: i need some more explanation please why because am new to android studio.how to add those list or grid icons optionsmenu icons how to visible and invisible option icons and this entire thing in android navigationdrawer with home fragment view.that options items icon in rightside middle of the screen.how to change toolbar for individual fragment also is it possible along with drawer

Comment: Ohh. So i have to explain everything and that is not possible on #SO @Harsha

Comment: oh not a problem can you provide any reference links for better understanding.i dont want to disturb.am plan to design like android telugu matrimoney app like for those optionitem icons.Thank you

Comment: how to place those list and grid items and how to change the icons from menu.xml with visible gone properties or any otehr please help me

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/menus.html @Harsha

Comment: hi pratik please can you post that options menu methode and list and grid changing sample snippet please help me.

Comment: hi am able to change the list and grid view data when user clicked on options menu icon but how to replace list with grid and list icons

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20614728/1318946 @Harsha

Comment: thanks all providing sample links and give some valuable information.finally achieved it.options menu icon changing and list grid views.but how to replace grid with costume layout.

Comment: setLayoutManager(isProductViewAsList ? new LinearLayoutManager(this) : new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));  here we need to set cusome grid row layout

Comment: @PratikButani Can you please  tell me isProductViewAsList about this variable and where will i declared? or can you plz send me full code.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found solution with the starting of activity I have set **`LinearLayoutManager`** like:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mProductListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

after that **`onOptionsItemSelected`** written like:

```
case R.id.menu_product_change_view:
     isViewWithCatalog = !isViewWithCatalog;
     supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
     //loading = false;
     mProductListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(isViewWithCatalog ? new LinearLayoutManager(this) : new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
     mProductListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
     break;
```

and changing view in **`onCreateViewHolder`** like:

```
@Override
public ProductRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(isViewWithCatalog ? R.layout.product_row_layout_list : R.layout.product_row_layout_grid, null);
    ProductRowHolder mh = new ProductRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}
```

From Starting to Ending you have to manage **isViewWithCatalog** variable for displaying which layout first.

Comment: What is  `isViewWithCatalog` how to get that?

Comment: @R2R `isViewWithCatalog` is boolean variable defined in that activity, which will decide which layout will be come first.

Comment: I'd use a strategy pattern here rather!

Comment: @Skynet How you will use a strategy pattern here?

Comment: `isViewWithCatalog` is also defined in adapter!

Comment: Yeah, That I have passed in argument of constructor. @SavaDimitrijević

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Thank you for your upvote : now Q/A both are equal 32:32 :D @SavaDimitrijević

Comment: @pratik-butani can you please update your answer with full adapter constructor ? and how you pass this `isViewWithCatalog ` variable in MainActivity ?

Answer (score 13):

In this [SDK samples](https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html) there is a complete example however it uses one layout file for both LayoutManagers

For keeping the scrolling position when switching the layout they used this function

```
public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
    int scrollPosition = 0;

    // If a layout manager has already been set, get current scroll position.
    if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
        scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    switch (layoutManagerType) {
        case GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), SPAN_COUNT);
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
            break;
        default:
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
    }

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
}
```

Comment: I know there's a long time since this answer, I see the current example page is not found, please If there's a complete example like it inform me

Comment: see this
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/77b5d39/samples/browseable/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.java

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem by setting the adapter again to the `RecyclerView`, after changing the layout manager.

```
listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: After scrolling to 30-40 items and then if i try to change view and it will be start again with 1 position to scroll. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @PratikButani,Try to use  recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position); after set new LayoutManager.

Comment: how I can recover the adapter position? I'm thinking about to create a method who save the last position got it by onBindViewHolder but still thinking there is a better way

Comment: This definitively solve my same issue

Answer (score 2):

I think after scrolling and changed back to grid view, the first item is not recreated. I solved this by override `getItemViewType()` and inflate the layout files in `onCreateViewHolder` accordingly.