# using two layout for single item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am trying to switch `setLayoutManager` between `LinearLayoutManager`(List) to `GridLayoutManager`(GridView) on toggle button it  is working fine but when the layout changes for list to  grid its giving me an exception in list view i am showing extra data than girdView and setting texts cant not find this Textviews in gridView single item file so its giving me an error can you please guide how can i handle two layouts and views in single Adapter 
this is my Adapter Code

```
 public class SavedAlbumAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SavedAlbumAdapter2.ItemViewHolder> {


    private final GlideRequest<Drawable> request;

    private ArrayList<AlbumLocalObj> itemModels;
    private static final int LIST_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int GRID_ITEM = 1;
    private ClickListener mListener;
    private LocalPreferences localPreferences;


    public SavedAlbumAdapter2(Activity context, ArrayList<AlbumLocalObj> values, ClickListener clickListener) {
        itemModels = values;
        this.mListener = clickListener;
        localPreferences = new LocalPreferences(context);

        int reqWidth = ((HomeActivity) context).screenWidth / 2;
        request = GlideApp.with(context)
                .asDrawable()
                .centerCrop()
                .override(reqWidth, reqWidth)
                .transition(withNoTransition());


    }


    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        if (viewType == LIST_ITEM) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_gallery2, parent, false);
        } else {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_gallery, parent, false);
        }
        return new ItemViewHolder(itemView, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AlbumLocalObj model = itemModels.get(position);

        holder.img_label.setText(model.getName());
        holder.tv_count.setText(String.valueOf(model.getCount()));
        initializeViews(model, holder, position);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (localPreferences.isGridViewEnabled()) {
            return GRID_ITEM;
        } else {
            return LIST_ITEM;
        }
    }

    private void initializeViews(AlbumLocalObj model, final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {


        if (model.getMediaFileObject() == null)
            holder.gallery_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_empty_fol);

        else {
            request.load(model.getMediaFileObject()).listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Log.i("glide_action", "failure");
                    clearResource((MediaFileObject) model);

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    clearResource((MediaFileObject) model);
                    Log.i("glide_action", "success");
                    return false;
                }
            })

                    .into(holder.gallery_img);


        }


    }


    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int piecesAtPos);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, int piecesAtPos);

    }

    private void clearResource(MediaFileObject item) {
        try {

            if (item.getInputStream() != null) {
                Log.i("resource", "clear");
                item.getInputStream().close();
                item.setInputStream(null);
                //Log.i("closing_str", pos + "");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemModels.size();
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        SquarImageView gallery_img;
        TextView img_label;
        TextView tv_count;
        ImageButton info;
        private ClickListener mListener;


        ItemViewHolder(View itemView, ClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            gallery_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            info = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info);
            img_label = itemView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            tv_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);

            this.mListener = listener;
            info.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            mListener.onItemLongClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my layout for single item of grid View

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_add_messages"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="1dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SquarImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@color/darkColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="7dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="akhskajhskjahkasjkhajskhjksasahjksahjkshajksahkjsahkjshjksjhakjhskjah"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="lahslahashkjjsahshjaksjhaksajhksahkjsahjksahkjsahjksahkjsahkjsahjksajhksahkjsakhjsahkjsahkjsahsklhask"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="7dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/info_white" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is for list item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/album_item_background" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/album_item_background">

        <SquarImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kajhskahskhas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="kajhskahskhas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/info"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

in my list view there are extra textview and button when i change list view to grid it can not find that views what should i do? do i have to create separate adapter?or how can i handle this in single adapter please help me

Comment: I hope, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581712/android-recyclerview-change-layout-file-list-to-grid-onoptionitemselected help for you.

Comment: you need to handle this in the viewHolder also. as you are finding the views in both scenarios of the viewType. I think this solves your problem. Even you cant give a try to Debug option at two pints 1. where you are inflating the Layout 2. in your ViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

Why do the extra TextViews in List item layout is having the same id?

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="kajhskahskhas" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="kajhskahskhas" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2" />
```

Comment: Add different id for the extra TextViews and give to ViewHolder and check again.

Comment: i just want to present my scenario i know there are same ids let me change them

Comment: but this is not  my problem in when i change to gridview holder cannot find those textview in my layout thats actual problem

Comment: Your code is fine. Have you debugged and checked whether the Adapter is taking correct layout when you switch from Grid to List?