# How to switch to vertical and Horizontal Linearlayoutmanager in Recycleview onclick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm looking to implement Button to switch the Recycle view inbetween horizontal and vertical layout.
If Recycleview is originally in Vertical Position then change to Horizontal on Click of button and vice versa.

My Logic is

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 //If Recycleview is in Horizontal then 
   mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new    LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

 //If Recycleview is in Vertical then 
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Have you tried this already? what is the issue?

Comment: Issue is I don't know how to implement to switch back and forth between two gridlayout i.e Horizontal and vertical on click of button..

Comment: Look at following SO question https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393588/132121 or here https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2s6zd5/recyclerview_change_layout_between_listgrid_on/

Answer (score 1):

Late answer
But hope someone will find this helpful

Kotlin code

```
var directionFlag = 0

    binding.yourView.setOnClickListener {
    
                binding.yourRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                    this,
                    1 - directionFlag, false
                )
                directionFlag=1-directionFlag
            }
        }
```

Java code

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new
                        LinearLayoutManager(this,
                        1 - directionFlag, false));
                directionFlag =1-directionFlag;

            }
        });
```